# Convert Big SQL to Graphical Representation

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Recently I have started working on a project wherein we are using Huge SQL statements for preparing some Materialized Views, which are being used for generating reports.

SQL Query being used are huge (600-700 lines, having many joins, pivots and what not). I need to understand the queries and make changes. We are using SQL Developer as tool to connect database.

Is there any way in SQL Developer or any other tool, wherein we can copy paste the query and see the graphical representation of it for a better overall view and quick understanding ?

Answer (score 0):

For conversion of Plain SQL to a graphical model view is not easily achievable as the SQL Table, view entities may vary from Database to database and use to use.

But you can make your SQL mode modular using Scratch editor,

In your SQL Developer:

1. Under **Tools** Menu, select **Migration** option
2. In that Select **Scratch editor**
3. You will get 2 split windows.
   [Scratch Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4SmW.jpg)
4. Once you paste your code in the left window, click on **Translate** (**>>**) option.
5. Your query will look more Modular and view-able.

**OR**

You can simply paste your code in SQL Developer editor and press **Ctrl + F7**

Hope this Helps!!
Let me know if you need any more help

Comment: SQL is already well indented using Crtl+F7 in SQL Developer, Something graphical will help better.

Comment: If i am getting you correct, for your need you need to convert the existing **RDBMS Database to Graph Database**, here in this site http://neo4j.com/developer/graph-db-vs-rdbms/
it mentions the points to be kept in mind
As per me there are **no tool available which can give you a direct conversion**. But you can read through this research paper for more info
http://www.inf.uniroma3.it/~torlone/pubs/grades2014.pdf